# How to check the shape of multiple arrays contained in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got a list containing multiple arrays, and I wrote the following codes try to see shape[0] of these arrays,

```
for i in xrange(len(list)):
    k = list[i].shape[0]
    print k
```

the outputs were correct, but I want to **check** these shape[0], that is, if they are the same, the function would continue, otherwise, if they are not the same number, the function breaks. How to do this? Feel free to give me advice, thanks a lot.

## Update

I created a list named 'ab' containing 3 different arrays, and used errors and exceptions codes to check the shape[0]:

```
ab = [np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]), 
      np.array([[1,2,3]]), 
      np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0,1,2],[0,9,9]])]

for i in xrange(len(ab)):
k = ab[i].shape[0]
print k

try:
    all(x.shape[0]==ab[0].shape[0] for x in ab)
    print 'True'
except ValueError:
    print 'False'
```

but the outputs were:

```
2
1
4
True
```

the outputs were wrong, where did I make a mistake?

Comment: So, `list[i]` would be an array, right? If so, what do you want to check its `shape[0]` against?

Comment: `for i in xrange(len(list))` is not pythonic. use `for l in list` instead!

Comment: It's good practice not to name your list `list` as `list` is the name of a useful builtin.  It's a bug waiting to happen when you come back in a month and add code that needs the builtin.

Comment: For the sample case, how do you expect it to behave there? You said the outputs were wrong, so what's the expected o/p?

Comment: @Divakar because the shape[0] of three arrays were not the same.

Comment: Right, so what do you expect the o/p to be and why?

Comment: @Divakar I think the output should be 'False' because three arrays in 'ab' have different shape[0].

Comment: Just store the shape[0] of list[0] and at each iteration starting from the second list elem, i.e. second array in that list keep checking against the stored one and break or continue based on it.

Comment: @Divakar Yeah I am thinking to solve this that way, and I think the codes above were fine, but somehow the output was wrong, and I could not find where the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

```
all(x.shape[0]==list[0].shape[0] for x in list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `set` comprehension to create a set of unique shapes then check if the length of the set is more than 1:

```
shapes = {arr.shape[0] for arr in my_list}
if len(shapes) > 1:
    # return None
```

Or as a better way try to apply a numpy function on your array, if they are not in same shape it will raise a `ValueError`:

```
try:
    np.hstack(my_list)
except ValueError:
    # rasise exception or return None
```